# Commutator of massless scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, correlation-functions

Hello I'm trying to calculate $\langle 0|[\phi(x),\phi(0)]|0\rangle$ where $\phi (x)$ is a free massless scalar field.

I've computed $$\langle 0|\phi (x) \phi (0)|0\rangle = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{(x_0 - i\epsilon)^2 - (\vec x)^2}$$ where $x = (x_0, \vec x)$ and I am using the (+, -, -, -) signature.

I'm confused about computing the commutator. If I try to compute it I get something like $$\frac{i\epsilon}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{((x_0 - i\epsilon)^2 - (\vec x)^2)((-x_0 - i\epsilon)^2 - (\vec x)^2) },$$ where I have discarded terms of $O(\epsilon^2)$.

I cannot see that this will simplify to anything meaningful or simple and how I this will be 0 when $x$ is spacelike. Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: Do you know about the properties of the propagator? one thing I should mention as a start is that you should get an integral for $\langle 0\left| \phi(x)\phi(0) \right|0 \rangle$ (which is the propagator)

Comment: I've already computed the propagator, it is given as above which I know is correct. I'm asking how to compute the commutator.

Comment: The expecration value of the commutator is called *causal propagator*, so you are computing the causal propagator. In view of its causal properties, its support is concentrated inside the light cone. Since the field is massless, its support is concentrated exactly on this  cone (its surface). You should find it from your computations.

Comment: Try to use $1/(z \pm  i0_+) = vp 1/z  \mp i \pi \delta (z) $

Comment: @ValterMoretti I ended up simplifying this to $<0|[\phi (x), \phi (0)]|0> = \frac{\epsilon}{(x^2)^2}$. This makes physical sense as it is 0 unless x^2 is null which it must be for a massless particle. But I'm unsure of my denominator. Also how do I use the principle value expression you posted with $\frac{1}{(z -i\epsilon)^2 - y^2}$?

Comment: @CStarAlgebra See my answer where I performed all computations till the final expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\langle 0|\phi (x) \phi (0)|0\rangle &= \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{(x_0 - i0_+)^2 - (\vec x)^2} \\ &= \frac{1}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}\left(\frac{1}{(x_0 - i0_+) - |\vec x|}
- \frac{1}{(x_0 - i0_+) + |\vec x|}\right)\:,\end{align}
that is

\begin{align} \langle 0|\phi (x) \phi (0)|0\rangle  &= \frac{1}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}\left(\frac{1}{x_0 - |\vec x| - i0_+ }
- \frac{1}{x_0 + |\vec x|- i0_+ }\right)\\ & = \frac{1}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}\left(PV \frac{1}{x_0 - |\vec x| }-
PV \frac{1}{x_0 + |\vec x| }\right) +  \frac{\pi i}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}
\left(\delta(x_0 - |\vec x| )-
\delta(x_0 + |\vec x| )\right)\:.\end{align}
Similarly

\begin{align} \langle 0|\phi (0) \phi (x)|0\rangle &=  \frac{1}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}\left(PV \frac{1}{-x_0 - |\vec x| }-
PV \frac{1}{-x_0 + |\vec x| }\right) +  \frac{\pi i}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}
\left(\delta(-x_0 - |\vec x| )-
\delta(-x_0 + |\vec x| )\right)\:.\end{align}

Taking the difference, using $PV1/(-z) = -PV 1/z$ and $\delta(z)=\delta(-z)$, we have an expression for the causal propagator like this
$$\langle 0|[\phi (x), \phi (0)]|0\rangle  =   \frac{2\pi i}{8\pi^2 |\vec x|}
\left(\delta(x_0 + |\vec x| )-
\delta(x_0 - |\vec x| )\right)\:.\tag{1}$$
Using $$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{\left|\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}\bigg |_{x_i}\right|}\tag{2}$$
where $x_i$ are distinct simple zeros of $f$, the found identity can be recast into the form
$$\langle 0|[\phi (x), \phi (0)]|0\rangle =   -\frac{4\pi i}{8\pi^2}
\mbox{sgn}(x_0)\delta(x^2_0 - (\vec x)^2 )\:.$$
Barring wrong coefficients (please check everything!), the final result should be
$$\langle 0|[\phi (x), \phi (0)]|0\rangle =   \frac{1}{2\pi i }
\mbox{sgn}(x_0)\delta(x^2_0 - (\vec x)^2 )\:.$$
It is evident that the right-hand side vanishes for spacelike related arguments of the causal propagator. However it also vanishes for timelike related arguments! This is a feature of free massless theories in flat spacetime.

Comment: Thank you @ValterMoretti, one question, where did the sgn function come from?

Comment: It arises comparing (1) and (2). I have corrected an overall wrong sign.